# Where can I find galaxy rotational data?

Tags: star, galaxy, data-analysis, rotation

I want to do a small project of generating rotational curves for different galaxies, and need data for some prominent stars in other galaxies (data needed: distance from center, rotational velocity) to generate basic rotational curves.
Where can I get this? I found this resource: [NASA/IPAC Extragalactic Database](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/), but there's no rotational data for stars (at least I can't find)

Comment: Don't have time to check out the references in this link and see if they could make an answer, but maybe they'll be useful: [Where can I find Galaxy Rotation Curve Data?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Where-can-I-find-Galaxy-Rotation-Curve-Data)

Comment: Hello, I don't know if you can read my response but I checked out some of the links in that before too. What they present are already made rotational curves of galaxies and not the data for each star itself, but thank you. I will check all the resources linked there

Comment: With the exception of very nearby dwarf galaxies, we don’t have velocities for individual stars in other galaxies.

Comment: Hi Hardek, if you want a user to receive a notification about your response, you can tag them with an "@" followed by their username.